# Low Memory Usage High CPU mysqld

Tags: mysql, performance, database-tuning, mysqltuner, performance-tuning

I'm managing a server with medium to high traffic.

It serves a wordpress website.

It seems that it use a lot of CPU (over 300% at some points) and always stack around 15% of memory usage.

It is a MySQL 5.7 server with InnoDB engine under nginx and php7-fpm.

Server has 16GB RAM

I tried to tune with mysqltuner but that doesn't help

Here is my mysqld.cnf

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 64M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 192M
query_cache_type        = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10G

#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/lib/mysql/Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal-slow.log
slow_query_log_file     = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
slow_query_log          = 1
#long_query_time = 5
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
```

Let me know what to tune on the above

Kind Regards

**Update**

The problem was solved but not on the current server.
I created an image of the VPS and requested another virtual machine. Copied that on the new server and the problem solved.
I can only imagine that there was a faulty hard drive on the initial machine.

I accepted @Rick James answer as correct because after debugging mysql slow query log, as he suggested, I found that all the slow queries reported didn't make any sense.

Comment: Downvote? Why? Isn't my question legit or something?

Comment: Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here.
complete (not edited) my.cnf-ini 
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
C) complete MySQLTuner.com  report if readily available - 7 or more days uptime is helpful
D) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop   OR  top for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Thank you for the comment. I'll collect the information and edit the answer the next few days because we restarted MySQL few hours ago

Comment: For the first cut, 1 full business day or more will be enough to get the most significant tuning items uncovered.  As a matter of fact, if you only post thru C) Mysqltuner repot after at least 1 full business day, we can get the most significant details on the table.

Comment: Rather than adding your own Answer OR adding a Comment with your links to data, Edit your Question with a line for the Link Content with a date, such as "my.cnf as of May 19" and then paste your link, please.

Comment: Posting information requested May 18, 18 will allow some constructive advice - let us know when it is posted, please.

Comment: remember this comment?   I'll collect the information and edit the answer the next few days because we restarted MySQL few hours ago – fat_mike May 19 at 1:51   we really need your help to post this information.  Everyone knows your are busy (probably overwhelmed with requests).   Thanks

Comment: Sure yes I remember. I'm trying to get more info based on @Rick James  mentioned in his answer. Basically `long_query_time` set to 1 gave me more queries than I can handle at the moment.

Comment: Some advice needs to be questioned and modified when you try it and you are overwhelmed with slow queries.  If you will post your slow query log, no matter how big it is, I will help you identify the MOST used and MOST time consuming, to be addressed one at a time with EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT …..  For additional assistance please find contact information in my profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are inefficiencies in the Query cache.

```
query_cache_size        = 192M
```

Change that to 50M.

That is one of the few cases where tuning can help with "high CPU".  Usually you need to check the indexes and query formulation.  So...

Find a couple slow queries, present to us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table(s) involved, and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  Then we can continue this discussion.

Oh, good; I see that the slowlog is already on, with a useless value for `long_query_time`; change it to `1`.  After a day, use `pt-query-digest` (or `mysqldumpslow -s t`) to find the 'worst' queries.

Comment: All the slow queries reported don't make any sense. Shouldn't be slow. See my updated question and why this is the correct answer to MY question.